# Python- Pandas Subtract columns value in ascending order value of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Have a dataframe mortgage_data with columns name mortgage_amount and month (in asceding order)

`mortgage_amount_paid = 1000`

mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month 
mark     400              1
mark     500              2
mark     200              3
```

How to deduct  and update `mortgage_amount` in ascending order or month using `mortgage_amount_paid` row by row in a dataframe
and add a column `paid_status` as yes if mortgage_amount_paid is fully deducted for that amount and no if not like this

if `mortgage_amount_paid = 1000`
mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month  mortgage_amount_updated  paid_status 
mark     400              1         0                     full
mark     500              2         0                     full
mark     200              3       100                     partial
```

ex:

if `mortgage_amount_paid = 600`

mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month  mortgage_amount_updated  paid_status 
mark     400              1         0                     full
mark     500              2       300                     partial
mark     200              3       200                     zero
```

tried this:

```
mortgage_amount_paid = 600

# amount saved - debt
m1 = df['mortgage_amount'].cumsum().sub(mortgage_amount_paid)
# is it positive?
m2 = m1>0
# is the previous month also positive?
m3 = m2.shift(fill_value=False)

df['mortgage_amount_updated'] = (m1.clip(0, mortgage_amount_paid)
                                   .mask(m3, df['mortgage_amount'])
                                 )
df['paid_status'] = np.select([m3, m2], ['zero', 'partial'], 'full')
```

error: i have given mortgage_amount_paid=400. paid status should be paid,zero,zero. i'm getting paid,partial,zero

and

```
mortgage_amount_paid = 600

m = df['mortgage_amount'].cumsum()

df['paid_status'] = np.select(
    [m <= mortgage_amount_paid,
     (m > mortgage_amount_paid) & (m.shift() < mortgage_amount_paid)
     ],
    ['full', 'partial'],
    default='zero'
)
df['mortgage_amount_updated'] = np.select(
    [df['paid_status'].eq('full'),
     df['paid_status'].eq('partial')],
    [0, m-mortgage_amount_paid],
    default=df['mortgage_amount']
)
```

error : if mortgage_amount_paid=1 paid_status should be partial,zero,zero. i'm getting partial zero,zero,zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a function:

```
def new(mortgage_amount_paid, df):
    m = df.mortgage_amount.cumsum()
    n = mortgage_amount_paid
    df['paid_status'] = np.where(m < n, 'full', 
             np.where(m - n < df.mortgage_amount, 'partial', 'zero'))
    return df # You do not have to since it does inplace replacement


new(600, df)
   name  mortgage_amount  month paid_status
0  mark              400      1        full
1  mark              500      2     partial
2  mark              200      3        zero

new(1000, df)
   name  mortgage_amount  month paid_status
0  mark              400      1        full
1  mark              500      2        full
2  mark              200      3     partial

new(100, df)
   name  mortgage_amount  month paid_status
0  mark              400      1     partial
1  mark              500      2        zero
2  mark              200      3        zero

new(2000, df)
   name  mortgage_amount  month paid_status
0  mark              400      1        full
1  mark              500      2        full
2  mark              200      3        full
```

Comment: @hacaho that should be a new question. The edit makes this solution obsolete. yet before the edit this solution was perfect. Also note that SO gives ideas and one should be able to implement them thus solving the biger problem.

Comment: @hacaho Note that this is a whole problem. You might find it hard for someone to help you on it since it is dealing with the whole project you have at hand. Thanks for the tag, but The answer I gave here is all that I have. You can contact me privately for further assistance, but hopefully someone will respond to you soon

Comment: @hacaho wait abit probably someone will respond. If not you can send an email. Please read carefuly my direct contact conditions. And if you are okay with that then you can contact me.

Comment: mortgage_amount_updated column is not updated

Comment: it it possible to add

Answer (score 1):

I added a few extra columns, and used the remaining amount to determine the status, not the other way around. It solves the issue and passed your test cases:

```
df['cumsum'] = df['debt'].cumsum()
df['previous']= df['cumsum'] - df['debt']
df['paid']=mortgage_amount_paid-df['previous']

df['remaining'] = np.select(
    [(df['paid'] >= df['debt']),
     ((df['paid']<df['debt']) & (df['paid']>0)),
     df['paid']<=0],
    [0, df['debt']-df['paid'],df['debt']],
    default=df['debt']
)

df['status'] = np.select(
    [(df['remaining'] ==0) ,
     (df['remaining'] <df['debt']),
     (df['remaining']==df['debt'])
     ],
    ['full', 'partial','zero'],
    default='zero'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a class aproach

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":['mark','mark','mark'],   "mortgage_amount":[400,500,200],  "month":[1,2,3] })
        
class MortageUpdate(object):
    def __init__(self,df: pd.DataFrame, mortgage_amount_paid: float):
        self.mortgage_amount_updated = mortgage_amount_paid
        df[['mortgage_amount_updated','paid_status']] = df.apply(lambda x: self.update_mortage(x['mortgage_amount']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
        self.df = df
        
    def update_mortage(self, mortgage_amount):
        if mortgage_amount <= self.mortgage_amount_updated and self.mortgage_amount_updated > 0:
            self.mortgage_amount_updated = self.mortgage_amount_updated - mortgage_amount
            return 0, 'full'
        elif mortgage_amount > self.mortgage_amount_updated and self.mortgage_amount_updated > 0:
            self.mortgage_amount_updated = self.mortgage_amount_updated - mortgage_amount
            return abs(self.mortgage_amount_updated), 'partial'
        else:
            return abs(mortgage_amount), 'zero'
```

---

```
MortageUpdate(df, 600).df
    
    name   mortgage_amount   month   mortgage_amount_updated   paid_status
0   mark               400       1                         0   full
1   mark               500       2                       300   partial
2   mark               200       3                       200   zero
```

---

```
MortageUpdate(df, 1000).df

    name   mortgage_amount   month   mortgage_amount_updated   paid_status
0   mark               400       1                         0   full
1   mark               500       2                         0   full
2   mark               200       3                       100   partial
```

---

```
MortageUpdate(df, 100).df
    
    name   mortgage_amount   month   mortgage_amount_updated   paid_status
0   mark               400       1                       300   partial
1   mark               500       2                       500   zero
2   mark               200       3                       200   zero
```