# Python- Pandas Subtract columns value in ascending order value of a columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataframe mortgage_data with columns name mortgage_amount and month (in asceding order)

input=
`mortgage_amount_paid = 1000`
`mortgage_amount_paid_date = 30-12-2019`

mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month  to_be_paid_date 
mark     500              1       01-01-2020
mark     500              2       01-02-2020
mark     500              3       01-03-2020
mark     500              4       01-04-2020
mark     500              5       01-05-2020
mark     500              6       01-06-2020
mark     500              7       01-07-2020
```

How to deduct  and update `mortgage_amount` and shift up to_be_paid_date in ascending order or month using `mortgage_amount_paid` row by row in a dataframe
and add a column `paid_status` as yes if mortgage_amount_paid is fully deducted for that amount and no if not like this

if `mortgage_amount_paid = 2000` and `mortgage_amount_paid_date = 30-12-2019`
mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month  to_be_paid_date  mortgage_amount_updated  paid_status  to_be_paid_date_updated
mark     500              1       01-01-2020         0                      full        30-12-2019
mark     500              2       01-02-2020         0                      full        30-12-2019
mark     500              3       01-03-2020         0                      full        30-12-2019
mark     500              4       01-04-2020         0                      full        30-12-2019
mark     500              5       01-05-2020        500                     zero        01-01-2020        
mark     500              6       01-06-2020        500                     zero        01-02-2020
mark     500              7       01-07-2020        500                     zero        01-03-2020
```

ex:

if `mortgage_amount_paid = 1800` and `mortgage_amount_paid_date = 30-12-2019`

mortgage_data:

```
name   mortgage_amount  month  to_be_paid_date   mortgage_amount_updated  paid_status  to_be_paid_date_updated

mark     600              1       01-01-2020          0                      full          30-12-2019
mark     600              2       01-02-2020          0                      full          30-12-2019
mark     600              3       01-03-2020          0                      full          30-12-2019
mark     600              4       01-04-2020         600                     zero          01-01-2020
mark     600              5       01-05-2020         600                     zero          01-02-2020
mark     600              6       01-06-2020         600                     zero          01-03-2020
mark     600              7       01-07-2020         600                     zero          01-04-2020
```

this code will update till the `mortgage_amount_updated` and   `paid_status`

[Python- Pandas Subtract columns value in ascending order value of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72621115/python-pandas-subtract-columns-value-in-ascending-order-value-of-a-column)

```
def new(mortgage_amount_paid, df):
    m = df.mortgage_amount.cumsum()
    n = mortgage_amount_paid
    df['paid_status'] = np.where(m < n, 'full', 
             np.where(m - n < df.mortgage_amount, 'partial', 'zero'))
    return df # You do not have to since it does inplace replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would convert your date column and `to_be_paid_date` to datetime like so

```
df["to_be_paid_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["to_be_paid_date"], format="%d-%m-%Y")
mortgage_amount_paid_date = datetime.strptime(mortgage_amount_paid_date,"%d-%m-%Y")
```

Then I would iterate over each row with `iterrows()` and compare the `to_be_paid_date` with `mortgage_amount_paid_date` and deduct your `mortgage_amount` value in the row from `mortgage_amount_paid` until it hits zero.